# Get the xpath of an element inside an iFrame for RobotFramework RIDE

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to get the xpath of a 'Form' element by its id that is inside an iframe.

[image]

In chrome xpath plugin when i query

> //iframe[contains(@id,'fraModalPopup')]

it gets me the iframe but when i try to get anything down the hierarchy it just returns null. e.g. if i try doing

> //iframe[contains(@id,'fraModalPopup')]/html   // returns null

or

> //iframe[contains(@id,'fraModalPopup')]/form[contains(@id='aspnetForm')]
>   // not sure if it is a right xpath statement - also returns null

would please anyone guide me how I can get hold on to the form element? I have to use this xpath inside RIDE (Robot Framework).

Comment: Please include XML code as code and **not** as image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iframe` is an element inside main HTML DOM that contains its own embedded HTML DOM. You don't need to use `iframe` as context node to find form inside frame, but you need to switch to that iframe

```
select frame  id=fraModalPopup
```

to be able to handle elements inside embedded HTML DOM (no need to add `"//iframe"` to XPath)

```
xpath=//form[@id='aspnetForm']
```

Comment: Thanks @Andersson. iframe selection before doing the xpath has done the job. Just for others, Don't forget to 'Unselect Frame' once work is done with the desired iframe. Please look at the 'Select Frame' section of the Selenium2Library documentation.